# Angular select multiple files without uploading and upload when clicking add button

Tags: angular, file-upload, upload, image-upload

I have an add-modal component for adding a house. When i press add a house i get a modal form to fill in and there is a button called upload file for that
I have an upload component where i can choose multiple files and upload it.
Than i have to fill other information and click on add to add a house. 
But i want to select files without directly uploading them and only upload  the files when i click on add house button.

```
UploadComponent.ts

import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpEventType, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload',
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.scss']
})
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {
  public imagePath;
  imgURL: any;
  public progress: number;
  public message: string;
  public files = []; @Output() public onUploadFinished = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public uploadFile = (files: File[]) => {
    if (files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const fileToUpload = files[i];
      formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    }
    this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/upload', formData, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})
    .subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        this.message = 'Upload success.';
        this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);
      }
    });


  // Preview image before upload
    const reader = new FileReader();
    this.imagePath = files;
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    reader.onload = (_event) => {
    this.imgURL = reader.result;
  };

  }




}
```

UploadComponent.html

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
  <div class="col-md-3">
      <img [src]="imgURL" height="200" *ngIf="imgURL">
    <input type="file" #file placeholder="Choose file" multiple (change)="uploadFile(file.files)" style="display:none;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="file.click()" >Upload File</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">

  </div>
</div>
```

AddModalComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { HouseService } from 'app/services/house.service';
import { HttpEventType, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ModalService } from 'app/services/modal.service';
import { FormControlsService } from 'app/services/form-controls.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-modal',
  templateUrl: './add-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-modal.component.css']
})
export class AddModalComponent implements OnInit {


  public response: {dbPath: ''};
// Add Modal
@ViewChild('template') modal: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(
    public modalProp: ModalService,
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    private houseService: HouseService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public fc: FormControlsService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {


    const validateImageUrl = '^(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))$';

    this.fc.name = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]);
    this.fc.price = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(10000)]);
    this.fc.description = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(150)]);
    this.fc.imageUrl = new FormControl('', []);

    this.fc.insertForm = this.fb.group({

            name : this.fc.name,
            price : this.fc.price,
            description : this.fc.description,
            imageUrl : this.fc.imageUrl,
            avalaible : true,

            });


  }


  onAddHouse() {
    this.modalProp.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.modal);
}

public uploadFinished = (event) => {
  this.response = event;
  this.fc.imageUrl.setValue(this.response.dbPath);
}



 // Method to Add new Product
 onSubmit() {
  const newProduct = this.fc.insertForm.value;

  this.houseService.insertHouse(newProduct).subscribe(
      result => {
          this.houseService.clearCache();
          this.modalProp.houses$ = this.houseService.getHouses();

          this.modalProp.houses$ .subscribe(newlist => {
              this.modalProp.houses = newlist;
              this.modalProp.modalRef.hide();
              this.fc.insertForm.reset();
              // this.rerender();

              });





          console.log('New Product added');

      },
      error => console.log('Could not add Product')

      );


}

}
```

AddModalComponent.html

```
<!-- ADD HOUSE MODAL START-->
<button class="btn btn-warning mb-3 float-right text-uppercase" *ngIf="modalProp.userRoleStatus == 'Admin'" (click)="onAddHouse()" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Huis toevoegen</button><br>

<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">ADD NEW HOUSE</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalProp.modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body text-center">
    <p class="list-group-item active text-center text-uppercase"></p>
    <form [formGroup]="fc.insertForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="houseTitle"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="name" formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Stad" aria-label="name" aria-describedby="houseTitle">
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fc.name.touched && fc.name.errors" class="errorMessage" >
            <span *ngIf="fc.name.hasError('required')">City Name is required.</span>
            <span *ngIf="fc.name.hasError('maxlength')">Only 50 characters allowed for House Name.</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="houseDescription"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></span>
            </div>
            <textarea formControlName="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Beschrijf het huis - Max 150 Tekens" aria-label="Description" aria-describedby="houseDescription"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="fc.description.touched && fc.description.errors">
            <span *ngIf="fc.description.hasError('required')">House Description is required.</span>
            <span *ngIf="fc.description.hasError('maxlength')">Only 150 characters allowed for House Description.</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <!-- <li class="list-group-item">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <input type="checkbox" formControlName="available" checked aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="House available" disabled>
          </div>
        </li> -->
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input formControlName="price" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Prijs">
          </div>
          <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="fc.price.touched && fc.price.errors">
            <span *ngIf="fc.price.hasError('required')">House Price is required.</span>
            <span *ngIf="fc.price.hasError('min')" >Negative price Not allowed</span>
            <span *ngIf="fc.price.hasError('max')">Max price allowes is 10000</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">

          <app-upload (onUploadFinished)="uploadFinished($event)"></app-upload>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <button  [disabled]="fc.insertForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">ADD</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </form>

  </div>
</ng-template>

<!-- ADD HOUSE MODAL START-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple array for pushing files, and then on submit iterate that array and do the post...

```ts
filesToUpload = [];

// called on file chosen
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
  this.filesToUpload.push(files[0]);
}
```

and on submit iterate files and make formdata, alternatively use `forkJoin` to run requests in paralell.

```ts
const reqs = [];
this.filesToUpload.forEach(x => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', x);
  // add your function
  reqs.push(this.myService.doSomething(formData)));
});

forkJoin(reqs).subscribe(......)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Upload Multiple Files With Angular:

In the component (TS) declare the selected file property (we will use it later):

```
export class SomeComponent {
  selectedFile: FileList | [] = [];
  //...
```

This is the HTML for the image upload:

```
<form>
  <input
    style="display: none"
    type="file" name="images" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput multiple="multiple">
  <button type="button" (click)="fileInput.click()">Select Files</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="onUpload()">Upload!</button>
</form>
```

Notice `style="display: none"` it's to hide the field, so only the button are visible.

`#fileInput` directs to the input element and used by the button to click on the element while clicking the button with this: `fileInput.click()`.

Back in the component:

```
  onFileChanged(event: any) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    console.log(this.selectedFiles);
  }

  onUpload() {
    //Here you send 'this.selectedFiles' to the server..
  }
```

### TL;DR (Too Long; Didn't Read)

This part is what really makes the multiple files upload available is:
`multiple="multiple"` on the **input field**.